# Generate a Json Serializable Generator using Build Runner in Flutter: Response is Succeeded, but no output is being generated

Tags: json, dart, flutter, json-serialization

I have an issue when trying to generate a Json Serializable Generator using Build Runner in Dart. First, I tried to do run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` to generate Json Serializable but it showed that it has a conflicting issue. So I run command  `--delete-conflicting-outputs`, to solve the conflicting issue.

After that I tried to run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` again  to regenerate the Json value. But the result that i got is like this:

[succeeded with no outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uit34.png)

So the output was : `[INFO] Succeeded after 137ms with 0 outputs (0 actions)`

I get so stressed because of it because all of generated-files were deleted. can somebody tell me what was happening and how to solve this issue?

I have been checking everywhere but still haven't found an answer.

Comment: It is better to put the output as text, not as image.

Comment: Did you add `@JsonSerializable()` annotation to your classes? Did you create a `build.yaml`, if yes, what does it contain?

Comment: Yes I add a @JsonSerializable(). but I didn't create the build.yaml, i only have the pubspec.yaml and it was ok before i run the --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: Use this command: flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Answer (score 10):

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to what the exact purpose of this command is

Comment: You saved my day. It works. It generates fromJson and toJson methods based on latest changes. Surprisingly it's not generated during build by default :O

Answer (score 1):

You should update your pubspec

```
dependencies:
  # Your other regular dependencies here
  json_annotation: <latest_version>

dev_dependencies:
  # Your other dev_dependencies here
  build_runner: <latest_version>
  json_serializable: <latest_version>
```

then run flutter pub run build_runner build

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the name of the .g.dart is written properly.

I ran into the same issue came here looking for a solution and when did not find one I noticed the name of the file to be generated is case sensitve.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not having the files underneath the /lib or /bin directories.

#### Checklist

Here's a [checklist of things to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63473168/2301224) when Json_serializable generator has succeeded with no outputs, but no files are generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-output
```