# Flutter JSON Serialization - Not generating *.g.dart files

Tags: json, flutter

I am new to flutter and the objective is to serialise complex JSON objects which contain other smaller objects.

Using the `json_serializable: ^2.0.0` and the `pubspec.yaml` file looks something like this.

```
dependencies:
  intl: ^0.15.7
  json_annotation: ^2.0.0
  built_value: ^6.7.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  json_serializable: ^2.0.0
  built_value_generator: ^6.7.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

The `user.dart` look like this

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: false)
class User {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final DateTime dateOfBirth;
  User({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}
```

I have tried `flutter pub run build_runner build` yet the file user.g.dart doesn't get created and I am facing issue with that.

I also have added the `build.yaml` file with following code

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      built_value_generator|built_value:
        generate_for:
          - model/*.dart
      json_serializable|json_serializable:
        generate_for:
          - model/*.dart
```

Can anyone let me know what I am missing here. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The constructor's argument shouldn't be optional

```
User({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth});
```

They should be obligatory:

```
User(this.firstName, this.lastName, this.dateOfBirth);
```

And the part

```
'user.g.dart';
```

should be matching the Uppercase User class:

```
part 'User.g.dart';
```

Comment: I've tried having optional arguments and it worked just fine. Happy Fluttering.

Comment: the obligatory argument stands correct but Uppercase doesn't really work. But the arguments.

Comment: Thanks, the optional argument constructor seemed to be the problem for me.

Comment: If you have a class like LoggedUser in a file named logged_user.dart, then use `part 'logged_user.g.dart'`

Comment: If you working with packages in your project, first need to go that package path and run 'flutter pub run build_runner build'

Answer (score 79):

## Checklist

- pubspec.yaml includes 3 packages:

```
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^4.8.1
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.4.7
  json_serializable: ^6.7.1
```

- you've run `flutter pub get`

  - if you get errors about versions at this stage, try older versions of [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable/versions), [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation/versions), [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner/versions)

    - note the Min Dart SDK listed on those linked pages
    - your pubspec.yaml `environment:` `sdk: ">=a.bb.c < x.y.z"`, your `a.bb.c` version must be `>=` than the Min Dart SDK listed on pub.dev for the package
    - if your Dart version is lower, try an older version of the json package which matches or is below your Dart version
- your class files are **underneath /lib or /bin**

  - can be subdirectories under those
  - json_serializable won't search every directory for files to generate.
- added import for json_annotation:

  - `import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';`
- you've added a `part` directive after `import` statements

  - your `part` file is named after your class *filename* (not the Class name itself), with a `g` added
  - e.g. for `CacheItem` class with ...
  - `cache-item.dart` class filename ...
  - `part 'cache-item.g.dart';` gets corresponding `part` directive.
  - the `part` directive is not named after your actual Class, but the class file name.
  - if Android Studio Dart Analyzer continues to give errors about missing `.g.dart` file after you're sure the file has been generated & named correctly, shut down Android Studio and restart it (analyzer sometimes goes insane & this may fix it. Restarting just the analyzer may not work.)
- you've added `@JsonSerializable()` above the class name
- you've created a **default constructor** for your class.

  - It can be empty, have optional named parameters, or positional parameters.
  - As long as your class fields are accessible (either through constructor or public setters & getters), json_serializable can handle it.  (i.e. don't have only _private properties and an empty constructor)
- you've written two methods calling private stub methods:

  - a factory `fromJson` method

    - e.g.: `factory CacheItem.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _CacheItemFromJson(json)`
  - a `toJson` method

    - e.g.: `Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$CacheItemToJson(this)`
  - stub methods are private (start with `_` underscore)
  - $tub methods have the `$`
  - stub methods have proper CaSe (i.e. [Pascal Case](https://wiki.c2.com/?PascalCase))
  - stub `factory` supplies `(Map<String,dynamic> json)` as argument
  - stub `toJson()` returns `Map<String,dynamic>`

When all that is complete, try running the generator from the command line or terminal in the project root directory...

In Flutter:

`flutter pub run build_runner build`

In pure Dart, this depends on your version, but one of these should work:

```
dart run build_runner build
pub run build_runner build
dart pub run build_runner build
```

If all goes well, click around in your project file explorer or `Reload from disk` and new files should show up such as `cache-item.g.dart` for the above example.

## Common Errors

##### `Bad state: Unexpected diagnostics:`

Seeing this output when running the build_runner is likely a problem with flutter and `json_annotation` depending on an incompatible version of `analyzer`. This happens with `json_serializable` versions *prior to 3.5* requiring a [dependency_override of analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63335160/2301224) to 0.39.14 or 0.39.17.

Your first move should be to try the latest version of [json_serilizable from pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) which [apparently doesn't have this dependency problem](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/704).

If you can't upgrade json_serializable you can try placing the override lines underneath `dev_dependences`:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.9.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  json_serializable: 3.3.0
  test: ^1.14.3

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: '0.39.14'
```

---

#### `[SEVERE] Nothing can be built, yet a build was requested.`

This error can happen when performing a `flutter pub run build_runner build` when we've added dependency in pubspec.yaml for `json_annotation` but are missing a dependency/dev_dependency for `json_serializable`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get:
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0
  some_other_packages:
```

Make sure you've got `json_serializable` package added as either a dependency or dev_dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get:
  json_annotation: ^4.3.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.1.4
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  json_serializable: ^6.0.1  #// ← do not forget
  test:
```

---

#### [SEVERE] Conflicting outputs were detected

#### pub finished with exit code 78

The full error is:

```
[SEVERE] Conflicting outputs were detected and the build
 is unable to prompt for permission to remove them. 
These outputs must be removed manually or the build 
can be run with `--delete-conflicting-outputs`. 
The outputs are: lib/some_generated_file.g.dart

pub finished with exit code 78
```

If one of the generated files could not be overwritten automatically, you'll get this error.

The fix is to re-run the same build command but with the added optional argument:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

This will (hopefully) allow previously generated .g.dart files to be deleted and rewritten.

---

#### `Could not generate` fromJson`code for`someField`.`

If you're json serializing a class that contains `someField` which is a Type for another custom class you've created, have you `@JsonSerializable()` that other custom class?

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class BuildingStatus {
  final Building building; // another custom class

  BuildingStatus(Building building);

  factory BuildingStatus.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$BuildingStatusFromJson(json);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$BuildingStatusToJson(this);
}


/// This guy needs serialization too.
@JsonSerializable()
class Building {
  final String name;

  const Building(this.name);

  factory Building.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$BuildingFromJson(json);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$BuildingToJson(this);
}
```

Without serializing the nested `Building` class, we'd see an error when running build_runner like:

```
Could not generate `fromJson` code for `building` because of type `Building`.
```

---

#### Instance of 'SomeNestedClass'

If we have nested serializable classes, we generally want the serialization to occur recursively.  i.e. the nested classes are also serialized.

To do that we would annotate our containing class with `explicitToJson: true` like:
`@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)`

So when we `toJson()` our `BuildingStatus` instance, instead of getting:

```
{"building": Instance of 'Building'}
```

... we would get:

```
{"building": {"name": "Empire State"}}
```

## Notes

**Subclass / Parent Class**

If your class is a child of a parent class and you want to Serialize fields/properties of child only, you can *annotate only the subclass*.  The parent class fields will automatically be found and included in the generated class files for the subclass.

If you want to be able to serialize/deserialize **both** parent and child *separately*, go ahead and annotate the base / parent classes with `@JsonSerializable` as well.

e.g. filename `account.dart`

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'account.g.dart';

class AccountBase {
  int? created;
  String? username;
  String? password;
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Account extends AccountBase {
  int? id;

  Account();

  factory Account.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$AccountFromJson(json);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$AccountToJson(this);
}
```

Produces:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'account.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

Account _$AccountFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Account()
  ..created = json['created'] as int?
  ..username = json['username'] as String?
  ..password = json['password'] as String?
  ..id = json['id'] as int?;

Map<String, dynamic> _$AccountToJson(Account instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'created': instance.created,
      'username': instance.username,
      'password': instance.password,
      'id': instance.id,
    };
```

#### Reference & Docs

- Example [project on github](https://github.com/ben-xx/json-serializable-test), relevant files under /bin/ and packages in pubspec.yaml
- [Flutter & Json](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)
- [Json_Serializable package](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)
- [Example](https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/tree/master/example) from the package authors

### Example

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'cache-item.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CacheItem {
  int created;
  String keywords;
  String response;

  CacheItem(this.created, this.keywords, this.response);

  factory CacheItem.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$CacheItemFromJson(json);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$CacheItemToJson(this);
}
```

#### Output

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'cache-item.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

CacheItem _$CacheItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CacheItem(
      json['created'] as int,
      json['keywords'] as String,
      json['response'] as String,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$CacheItemToJson(CacheItem instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'created': instance.created,
      'keywords': instance.keywords,
      'response': instance.response,
    };
```

---

#### Example Constructor Variant

This example is the same as above except the constructor is missing some fields and has `response` as optional.

It's fine.

The generator will just use the public (implicit) setters after instantiating the object to assign the values.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'cache-item.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class CacheItem {
  int? created;
  String? keywords;
  String? response;

  CacheItem({this.response});

  factory CacheItem.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) => _$CacheItemFromJson(json);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$CacheItemToJson(this);
}
```

#### Output

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'cache-item.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

CacheItem _$CacheItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CacheItem(
      response: json['response'] as String?,
    )
      ..created = json['created'] as int?
      ..keywords = json['keywords'] as String?;

Map<String, dynamic> _$CacheItemToJson(CacheItem instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'created': instance.created,
      'keywords': instance.keywords,
      'response': instance.response,
    };
```

Comment: This one was really helpful, most important thing is don't use extra dependencies, just use what is suggested by @Baker. +1

Comment: i've checked everything and it's confirm not generate those model-json conversion method

Comment: For my case, it is about .g.dart files name; I was trying to type "xx_quentity_model.g.dart" but my dart file name is "xx_quantity_model.dart" so, my .g.dart file were not generates so if you are not found any error in check list, maybe you can control the .g.dart file name(for type errors).

Comment: Great answer... Another thing to add to verification list: make sure you save before you generate the files... Otherwise, all new changes are not taken into consideration

Answer (score 8):

try running

```
>flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to generate .g files by just running the command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` and you are not getting your desired result then just try:

1. `flutter clean`
2. 'flutter pub cache repair'
3. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`
4. delete all the gradle temp files
5. then run `flutter pub get`
6. `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I got to know that , file has to be saved before running the command
`flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

I know answer seems so simple.

Comment: I edited a little to reduce the impression that you describe your own problem (users here get easily confused). I noticed that the file in question is not clearly identified. You might want to be more explicit. Otherwise thanks for your contribution.

Comment: exactly the same case for me when I just installed vs code and tried it :( Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 3):

The file name, class, and `part 'Book.g.dart';` should all match.

Comment: Your comment on Jalil's answer suggested you had this working with an optional argument constructor. Any chance you can drop the code into this answer? As changing from option to required arguments is the only thing that got this working for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this following error

error

```
[WARNING] json_serializable:json_serializable on lib/day10/models/sentence.dart:
Missing "part 'sentence.g.dart';".
```

I noticed that I had to change on the model file this `part 'Sentence.g.dart';` to this `part 'sentence.g.dart';` in other words, I had to lowercase it.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I had to add **hive_generator** package, along with the build_runner package.
If your model class name is for example transaction.dart, then it would be like this-
`part 'transaction.g.dart'`
Run the command-
`flutter packages pub run build_runner build` it will generate the transaction model for you.

Answer (score 2):

adding

```
json_serializable: ^6.0.0
```

to dev_dependencies solve it for me

Answer (score 1):

please check your **`part file name`**, such as:
if your dart filename is `user_model.dart`, your **part 'xxx.g.dart'** should be:

```
part 'user_model.g.dart'
```

it worked to my projcet. For me, the xxx.g.dart after part should be the .dart file name instead of the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Some times we forgot to save the files, please save the file then run the command.

```bash
flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Add "part 'your_class_name.g.dart'"

**Step 2:** Run this command on Terminal: flutter pub run build_runner build

**Example:**

```
part 'student.g.dart'

@JsonSerializable()
class Student{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Do not forget to save the file*** that has the `class` **even if it still has errors**

Then run the command on any terminal (o integrated terminal)...

But for Dart:

```
pub run build_runner build
```

And for Flutter:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Official reference link:

- https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable
- https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/tree/master/example