# Retrofit Flutter does not generate model-json conversion method

Tags: flutter, retrofit

I am following this official [guide](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) straight forward and it is obviously not generating `_$TaskFromJson` and `_$TaskToJson` methods ,

I've put it in 'task.dart' file and modified `part` as followed

**task.dart**

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:retrofit/retrofit.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

part 'task.g.dart';

@RestApi(baseUrl: "https://5d42a6e2bc64f90014a56ca0.mockapi.io/api/v1/")
abstract class RestClient {
  factory RestClient(Dio dio, {String baseUrl}) = _RestClient;

  @GET("/tasks")
  Future<List<Task>> getTasks();
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Task {
  String id;
  String name;
  String avatar;
  String createdAt;

  Task(this.id, this.name, this.avatar, this.createdAt);

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TaskFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TaskToJson(this);
}
```

and I run this command
`flutter pub run build_runner build`
but the generated part is as followed only without any `_$TaskFromJson` nor `_$TaskToJson`

**task.g.dart**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'task.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// RetrofitGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class _RestClient implements RestClient {
  _RestClient(this._dio, {this.baseUrl}) {
    ArgumentError.checkNotNull(_dio, '_dio');
    this.baseUrl ??= 'https://5d42a6e2bc64f90014a56ca0.mockapi.io/api/v1/';
  }

  final Dio _dio;

  String baseUrl;

  @override
  getTasks() async {
    const _extra = <String, dynamic>{};
    final queryParameters = <String, dynamic>{};
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    final Response<List<dynamic>> _result = await _dio.request('/tasks',
        queryParameters: queryParameters,
        options: RequestOptions(
            method: 'GET',
            headers: <String, dynamic>{},
            extra: _extra,
            baseUrl: baseUrl),
        data: _data);
    var value = _result.data
        .map((dynamic i) => Task.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
    return Future.value(value);
  }
}
```

I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360475/flutter-json-serialization-not-generating-g-dart-files) but not helping me as this question is talking about cannot generate at all, but mine is generate well with missing JsonSerialized methods. Somemore the answer suggested use Uppercase **User** filename which is definitely not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) is responsible for generating those methods. Just import it into your pubspec `dev_dependencies` section, run `flutter pub get` and `flutter pub run build_runner build`.

Answer (score 0):

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
logger: any
retrofit: any
json_annotation: any

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
build_runner: any
retrofit_generator: any
json_serializable: any

Use this version of package of all retrofit associated package
Surely it will work